# Viewing updates made to a class instance that is changed with a picker?

Tags: class, swiftui, foreach, picker

I have a picker that selects an instance of a class I made called Speaker, which is held in an environmentobject as a "master" list of all instances of the Speaker class.

```
// Picker implementation
struct Grammarian_Final_Count_View: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var session: tms
    @State var currentSpeaker: Speaker
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Form {
                Picker("", selection: $currentSpeaker) {
                    ForEach(session.allSpeakers) { s in
                        Text("\(s.name)")
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Grammar Results")
        }
    }
}
```

```
// Class definition
final class Speaker: ObservableObject, Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    @Published var ahCounts = ahCountables()
    @Published var grammerCounts = GrammarCountables()
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(self.id)
    }
    
    static func ==(lhs: Speaker, rhs: Speaker) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to select a new speaker with my picker, nothing changes. I suspect that it has something to do with using the @State wrapper for an instance of a class, but when I use other wrappers, like @ObservedObject or @StateObject, I get a whole laundry list of issues.

I've never had such an issue implementing a picker - normally takes 2 seconds, but this has completely stalled a day's worth of work just writing and deleted 2 dozen solutions.

Comment: try making `Speaker` a `struct` not a class (and remove the func hash things). Also try adding a `.tag()`, such as: 
`Text("\(s.name)").tag(s)`. Show the code of how you declare and pass your `tms` from the various Views into `Grammarian_Final_Count_View`

Comment: Identifiable and Hashable are probably a bad idea in a class. Try making Speaker a struct.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem you have can be fixed by using a `.tag()` in the Picker that matches the type of `currentSpeaker`, ie `Speaker` type.

However, nesting ObservableObjects is not a good idea and has shown in the past to create problems.
I suggest you use a struct for `Speaker` and ObservableObject for your `Tms`.

This example code shows how to use `session` and `currentSpeaker` in one view, and how
to pass them to your `Grammarian_Final_Count_View`, together with using `.tag(s)` in the Picker.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var session = Tms()  // <--- here
    @State var currentSpeaker = Speaker(name: "")
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(currentSpeaker.name)
        Grammarian_Final_Count_View(currentSpeaker: $currentSpeaker)  // <--- here
            .environmentObject(session)
            .onAppear {
                if let firstSpeaker = session.allSpeakers.first {
                    currentSpeaker = firstSpeaker
                }
            }
    }
}

struct Grammarian_Final_Count_View: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var session: Tms
    @Binding var currentSpeaker: Speaker  // <--- here
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Form {
                Picker("", selection: $currentSpeaker) {
                    ForEach(session.allSpeakers) { s in
                        Text("\(s.name)").tag(s)  // <--- here
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Grammar Results")
        }
    }
}

struct Speaker: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    //  var ahCounts = ahCountables()
    //  var grammerCounts = GrammarCountables()
}

class Tms: ObservableObject {
    @Published var allSpeakers = [Speaker(name: "name-1"),Speaker(name: "name-2"),Speaker(name: "name-3")]
}
```